# How to refer to separate @PropertySource in @PropertySources to get value

Tags: java, spring

I have a couple property files, described in configuration

```
@Configuration    
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(name="p1", value = "classpath:p1.properties"),
        @PropertySource(name="p2", value = "classpath:p2.properties")})
```

Both files have properties with the same keys and different values, for example:

```
prop1=11
prop2=12
```

and

```
prop1=21
prop2=22
```

How to refer to the right property source to use value? I mean smth like

```
@Value("${p1.prop1}")
private int prop11;

@Bean
public SomeBean someBean() {
    return new SomeBean(prop11);
}
```

but `@Value("${p1.prop1}")` is my wrong attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The two property sources will be merged into the same Spring [Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html). The last declared value for the same key in the your .properties files will override any previous value for the same key. If your read the JavaDoc of [@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) you will find the following statement:

> In cases where a given property key exists in more than one .properties file, the last @PropertySource annotation processed will 'win' and override.

Comment: Thank you, really - it's quite logically, besides, these properties can be got from environment, so having properties with the same keys would be ambiguous.